# Cannot get the attachments/media from a custom Wordpress post type?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image, underscores-wp

I'm attempting to get the attached/inserted images in my Wordpress `php` code that I inserted into a test post in the admin interface. I clicked the "Add Media" button and uploaded my pictures and updated the post (where `front-page` is the custom post type).

(I clicked this button):

[image]

However, I can't seem to retrieve the picture associated with that post for the life of me. If I set a `Feature Image` (thumbnail), I can get that, but not inserted images. Here's what I've tried:

**Looping Through Attachments** (No luck):

```
$attachments = query_posts(
                array(
                'post_type' => 'front-page',  // only get "attachment" type posts
                'post_parent' => $post->ID,   // only get attachments for current post/page
                'posts_per_page' => -1        // get all attachments
              )
            );
foreach($attachments as $attachment) {
    echo get_the_ID();
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
}
```

**wp_attached_image(post ID)** (No luck):

```
wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID );
```

**Getting all the posts** (No luck):

```
<?php
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'front-page', 
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'numberposts' => -1, 
    'post_status' => null, 
    'post_parent' => $post->ID 
); 
$attached_images = get_posts( $args );
echo $attached_images[0];
?>
```

**Getting the post gallery images** (No luck)

```
get_post_gallery_images( $post->ID );
```

I'm really lost as to why I can't retrieve the images. I've exhausted nearly every suggestion I could find online, and was wondering if it had something to do with my custom post type or what? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the resulting code with echo (as I am doing below) or print or output.
I managed to do it with this code a while ago.. hope it helps-(using fancybox in this one)

```
<?php
$attachments = get_posts( array( 
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_mime_type'=>'image',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_status' => 'any',
'post_parent' => $post->ID)
);

if ( $attachments ) {
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, full);     
$html = '<a class="fancybox" href="'.$src[0].'">';
$html .= wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'gallery-thumb') .'</a>';
echo $html;
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean this (the codex says you should use get_posts() in this case):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Show_attachments_for_the_current_post

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up fixing it:
(Commented so as to explain what I did).

```
<?php
        // Argument array to hold parameters for get_post() method.
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment', 
            'posts_per_page' => -1, 
            'post_status' => 'any', 
            'post_parent' => null
            );

        // Holds the URL of the image.
        $image_url = '';

        // If we have a thumbnail in the post, use that as the main image.
        if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
            $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID))[0];
        }
        // Otherwise, if we have an attachment image, use that as the main image.
        else if (get_posts($args)) {
            // Simple test to see if we can display attachments from any post.
            $attachments = get_posts($args);
            if ( $attachments ) {
                $first_photo = $attachments[0];
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($first_photo->ID , false );
            }
        }
        // If there are no images, just display the text. 
        else {
            echo "No images";
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
     <input name="name" type="image" src="resimler/azalt.gif" />
</form>
```

try this.

Print_r($_Request);  where you want to see . it will work .